# how do you implement make_folds function in ML

Tags: python, numpy

How do you implement make_folds function in ML

```
def make_folds(x, num_folds):
    """ Divides the array `x` along axis-0 into a list of equal-sized 
    sub-arrays.
```

x is numpy array

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

```
def make_folds(x, num_folds):
    """ Divides the array `x` along axis-0 into a list of equal-sized 
    sub-arrays."""
    assert len(x)%num_folds == 0, "Given array can not be split into {} equal-size subarrays".format(num_folds)
    return np.split(x, num_folds)
```

or directly using https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html if you want to do Kfold validation